# Swift get UITextView current cursor position and set the range to UIButton position value

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

My scenario, I am adding buttons into `UITextView`. Here, I need to add buttons side by side for that first I need to get current `cursor` range and set the range to `UIButton` x `position`.

My Code below

```
let firstButton:UIButton = UIButton()
firstButton.setTitle(" \(title)", for: .normal)
firstButton.titleLabel?.font = firstButton.titleLabel?.font.withSize(15)
firstButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
firstButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
firstButton.backgroundColor = .red
firstButton.tintColor = .white
firstButton.sizeToFit()
firstButton.frame = CGRect(x: <Here I need to add current cursor position>, y: 3, width: firstButton.frame.width + 15, height: firstButton.frame.height + 5)
growingTextView.addSubview(firstButton)
```

Here, below code I tried but showing error

```
var selectedRange = growingTextView.textView.selectedRange
```

> Error:Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGRect' with an argument
>   list of type '(x: NSRange, y: Int, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat)'

Current Output (If I add next button It should add current cursor position)

[image: Current output]

Expected Output

[image: Expected output]

Comment: `selectedRange` is an `NSRange` which is a location and a length. The location is the offset in the UTF-16 encoding of the text of the text view. What logic do you want to convert an offset to the text into an `x` coordinate for a button?

Comment: You should [edit] your question and clarify what you are actually trying to do. Maybe show a picture of the desired relationship between the current text selection and button position.

Comment: first of all Thank you very much for considering my question. I am struggling on adding the multiple UIButton side by side like a tagging concept within TextView. Here, I am using NextGrowingTextView with above code. I can add the UIButton but cant able to append one and another. I decided to get the current cursor position to make it for appending next button. Please help me some idea. @rmaddy

Comment: @rmaddy I updated buddy. Please check it and let me know some idea